# NIC teaming and vlan support in linux

Tags: linux, networking, vlan, bonding

Doeas anyone has idea about vlan support in linux with NIC teaming/bonding.In case of a switch I am not able to communicate however if I remove multiple vlan interfaces from NIC , I am able to communication.

Regards,

Comment: How did you set up your bonding interface and VLANs? Show your config.

Answer (score 2):

VLAN tagging is supported in Linux using the [802.1Q](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ip) module. NIC bonding is supported in Linux using the [bonding](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ifenslave) module. Every major distribution should include a kernel new enough that it supports these features.

**VLAN Tagging**

```
# ip link add link eth0 name eth0.200 type vlan id 200
# ip link show
```

This will create an interface `eth0.200` that is tagging for VLAN ID 200.

**NIC Bonding**

```
# ifconfig bond0 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.0.0
# ifenslave bond0 eth0 eth1
```

This will create an interface `bond0` with the IP address 192.168.0.1/16 composed of `eth0` and `eth1`.

The method to making these setting persistent is dependent upon your particular distribution of Linux.

Comment: I am able to communicate on single eth0 only if I break link eth0 i am not able to communicate on different sw between vlans.

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug in RHEl6 2.6-32.279 which was causing this issue.
Upgrading kernel will resolve it.

A bug was in 8021dq module.

Regards